# Map coordinates not decoding

Tags: objective-c, mkannotation, nscoding, nsarchiving

In my app, I am trying to save the pins that are on the map so that they are there when the user opens the app after it is terminated. I have conformed my mkAnnotation class to NSCoding, and implemented the two required methods. The annotations are all stored in a NSMutableArray in a singleton class, so I am really just trying to save the array in the singleton class. Everything is being encoded fine, but I do not think they are being decoded. Here is some code:
This is my MKAnnotation class:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapPoint : NSObject <MKAnnotation, NSCoding>
{
}

- (id)initWithAddress:(NSString*)address
        coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
                title:(NSString *)t;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

//This is an optional property from MKAnnotataion
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL animatesDrop;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL canShowCallout;

@property (copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *imageKey;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *image;

@end 

@implementation MapPoint

@synthesize title, subtitle, animatesDrop, canShowCallout, imageKey, image;
@synthesize address = _address, coordinate = _coordinate;

-(id)initWithAddress:(NSString *)address
       coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
            title:(NSString *)t {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _address = [address copy];
        _coordinate = coordinate;

        [self setTitle:t];

        NSDate *theDate = [NSDate date];

        subtitle = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:theDate
                                                  dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                  timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {

    [aCoder encodeObject:_address forKey:@"address"];

    NSLog(@"ENCODING coordLatitude %f coordLongitude %f ", _coordinate.latitude, _coordinate.longitude);
    [aCoder encodeDouble:_coordinate.longitude forKey:@"coordinate.longitude"];
    [aCoder encodeDouble:_coordinate.latitude forKey:@"coordinate.latitude"];

    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setAddress:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"address"]];

        NSLog(@"DECODING coordLatitude %f coordLongitude %f ", _coordinate.latitude, _coordinate.longitude);
        _coordinate.longitude = [aDecoder decodeDoubleForKey:@"coordinate.longitude"];
        _coordinate.latitude = [aDecoder decodeDoubleForKey:@"coordinate.latitude"];

        [self setTitle:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Here is my singleton class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class MapPoint;

@interface Data : NSObject
{
NSMutableArray *_annotations;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *annotations;

+ (Data *)singleton;
- (NSString *)pinArchivePath;
- (BOOL)saveChanges;

@end

@implementation Data

@synthesize annotations = _annotations;

+ (Data *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Data *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Data alloc] init];
        shared.annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    });
    return shared;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *path = [self pinArchivePath];
        _annotations = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
        if (!_annotations) {
            _annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)pinArchivePath {
    NSArray *cachesDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *cachesDirectory = [cachesDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

    return [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pins.archive"];
}

- (BOOL)saveChanges {
    NSString *path = [self pinArchivePath];

    return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[Data singleton].annotations
                                       toFile:path];
}

@end
```

In my viewDidLoad method on the map view controller, I try and place the annotations in the singleton array on the map with this:

```
for (MapPoint *mp in [Data singleton].annotations) {
        [_worldView addAnnotation:mp];
}
```

Comment: Where you decode it, try putting the NSLog _after_ the decode lines.

Comment: Ok that helped but the pins aren't showing up on the map when I reopen the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is in the `singleton` method in these lines:

```
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    shared = [[Data alloc] init];
    shared.annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //<-- problem line
});
```

The `shared = [[Data alloc] init];` line decodes and initializes the `annotations` array.

Then the `shared.annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` line re-creates and re-initializes the `annotations` array **thus discarding the just-decoded annotations** so the singleton always returns an empty array.

Remove the `shared.annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` line.



As already mentioned in the comment, the other minor issue, which causes simply confusion, is the placement of the `NSLog` where the coordinate is being decoded.  The `NSLog` should be *after* the decode is done.